# How to sleep in a QRunnable?

Tags: c++, qt

It seems `QRunnable` does not have a `sleep` method.
How can I call method like `QThread::sleep` in a `QRunnable` ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1. Don't use platform specific functions. The great advantage of Qt is that it is pretty easy portable. Don't ruin it just with `sleep`
2. You, can use `QThread::sleep` from `QRunnable` or `QtConcurent` only in *Qt 5*, as it is declared public there:

> void QThread::sleep ( unsigned long secs ) **[static protected]** // Qt 4.8
>
> void QThread::sleep(unsigned long secs) **[static]** // Qt 5.0

You can use mutex as workaround for earlier Qt versions:

```
QMutex m(QMutex::NonRecursive);
m.lock();
m.tryLock(timeout);
```

Mutex will fail to lock recursively and will wait for timeout.

Answer (score 3):

Just simply use `::sleep()` it isn't in Qt it's a POSIX.1-2001 function.

Also you can try this code, because `QThread::sleep()` calls `::Sleep()`

```
class mythreadhelper : public QThread
{
   public:
   static void mysleep(int ms)
   {
      return sleep(ms);
   }
};
```

This question was answered at [Qt Centre](http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/25825-How-to-quot-sleep-quot-inside-QRunnable-derived-class) with a response from Nokia Certified Qt Developer.

Comment: How can I call `::sleep()` ?

Comment: If you look at the code above it is called in the line: `return sleep(ms);`. So just simply type `sleep();` and put the amount of miliseconds in the parentheses.

Comment: the `::` implies that it is in the global scope, and is optional.  System or OS functions are often in the global scope, and sometimes just to distinguish these functions from member functions.  Kind of like how some people will put `this->` in front of their member function calls.

Comment: @totymedli I don't have a `::sleep` in my global slope. Is it the one in `<Windows.h>` ?

Comment: Not exactly. `QThread::sleep` sleeps for a number of *seconds*. As does posix's `::sleep`. However, on Windows `::Sleep` sleeps for a number of *milliseconds*.

Comment: @BeniBela which header has posix's `::sleep` ? `<unistd.h>` ? I'm on windows and probably don't have a `<unistd.h>`.

Comment: @CDT: You should use the QThread method since it is platform-independent. For Windows only there is ::Sleep in windows.h